# How to create a cupertinoactionsheet from database values

Tags: ios, flutter

I am trying to return a cupertinoactionsheet to use it on a future builder.  The values are stored locally

So far I manage to retrieve only the cupertinoactionsheetactions.

I'd tried to return the whole actionsheet but it fails

The goal is to make the app as more native looking as possible.
That is the reason I don't want to use any material widget

Any answer appeciated

Thank you very much

```
void _modalBottomSheetMenu() {
    showCupertinoModalPopup(
        context: context,
        builder: (builder) {
          return new Container(
            height: 450.0,
            color: Color(0xFF737373), 

            child: new Container(
                decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                    color: CupertinoColors.white,
                    borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: const Radius.circular(10.0),
                        topRight: const Radius.circular(10.0))),
                child: 
// some more code

                  new FutureBuilder(
                    future: plates,
                    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                      switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                        case ConnectionState.none:

                        case ConnectionState.waiting:
                          return new Text('loading...');
                        default:
                          if (snapshot.hasError)
                            return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                          else
                            return createListView(context, snapshot);
                      }
                    },
                  )
                ])),
          );
        });
  }


Widget createListView(BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    List<String> values = snapshot.data;
    return new ListView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: values.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new CupertinoActionSheetAction(
                //leading: new Icon(CupertinoIcons.directions_car),
                child: new Text(values[index]),
                onPressed: () => {
                      setState(() {
                        _carplate = values[index];
                      }),
                      Navigator.pop(context)
                    }),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the above code works, note that embedding all CupertinoActionSheetAction in one Container will result in all of them been highlighted when any one of them were been tapped.

Here is the official docs from flutter:

```
Future<void> _handleClickMe() async {
  return showCupertinoModalPopup<void>(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return CupertinoActionSheet(
        title: Text('Favorite Dessert'),
        message: Text('Please select the best dessert from the options below.'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          CupertinoActionSheetAction(
            child: Text('Profiteroles'),
            onPressed: () { /** */ },
          ),
          CupertinoActionSheetAction(
            child: Text('Cannolis'),
            onPressed: () { /** */ },
          ),
          CupertinoActionSheetAction(
            child: Text('Trifie'),
            onPressed: () { /** */ },
          ),
        ],
        cancelButton: CupertinoActionSheetAction(
          isDefaultAction: true,
          child: Text('Cancel'),
          onPressed: () { /** */ },
        ),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Below is how I have made the dynamic list of items perform the same  behavior. While the user is tapping an option just that CupertinoActionSheetAction will be highlighted, and also you will note a separator between items as expected.

```
void _showActionSheetIOS(context, Customer customer) {
    showCupertinoModalPopup(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) => CupertinoActionSheet(
        title: Text('Choose an option for ${customer.name}'),
         message: const Text('Your options are '),
          actions: _yourLstCustomerObjs
              .map((item) => CupertinoActionSheetAction(
                    child: Text(item.option),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                      _selectItem(item);
                    },
                  ))
              .toList(),
          cancelButton: CupertinoActionSheetAction(
            child: const Text('Cancel'),
            isDefaultAction: true,
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context, 'Cancel');
            },
          )),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should retrieve the values before showing the action sheet and then pass the values in `createListView` instead of the snapshot. Something like this:

```
void _modalBottomSheetMenu() async {
    List<String> values = await plates;
    showCupertinoModalPopup(
      context: context,
      builder: (builder) {
        return Container(
          height: 450.0,
          color: Color(0xFF737373),
          child: new Container(
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                color: CupertinoColors.white,
                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: const Radius.circular(10.0),
                    topRight: const Radius.circular(10.0))),
            child: createListView(context, values),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }


Widget createListView(BuildContext context, List<String> values) {
    return new ListView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: values.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new CupertinoActionSheetAction(
                //leading: new Icon(CupertinoIcons.directions_car),
                child: new Text(values[index]),
                onPressed: () => {
                      setState(() {
                        _carplate = values[index];
                      }),
                      Navigator.pop(context)
                    }),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much 
The full code is

```
Widget createListView(BuildContext context, List<String> values) {
    return Container(
        height: 300.0, 
        //width: 300.0, 
        child: new ListView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      shrinkWrap: false,
      itemCount: values.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return new Column(
          children: <Widget> [
            new CupertinoActionSheetAction(
                child: new Text(values[index]),
                onPressed: () => {
                  setState(() {
                    _carplate = values[index];
                  }),
                  Navigator.pop(context)
                }),

        ]);
      },
    ));
  }

  void _modalBottomSheetMenu() async {
    List<String> values = await plates;

    showCupertinoModalPopup(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) => CupertinoActionSheet(
        title: const Text('Choose Options'),
        message: const Text('Your options are '),
        actions: <Widget>[
          createListView(context, values)

        ],
        cancelButton: CupertinoActionSheetAction(
          child: const Text('Cancel'),
          isDestructiveAction: true,

          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context, 'Cancel');
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
```